# Laravel Scout toSql does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I am trying to get SQL query as a string from query builder. `toSql()` method works fine without laravel scout. I am using [this](https://github.com/YABhq/laravel-scout-mysql-driver) package for Fulltext search. Here is my code.

```
Post::toSql(); // Working without scout => select * form post
```

But I am getting an error when try to search

```
Post::search('test')->toSql();
```

> Method Laravel\Scout\Builder::toSql does not exist

How  Laravel Scout can be extended to add  a method `toSql` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

Post::search('test');

dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

Comment: Actually I want to use `toSql` query in a subquery. But  `DB::getQueryLog()` will print multiple queries and the expected query will be on the different index each time when conditions change.